# Orchard admin Users page tabs dont show up

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I need to use original Admin/Users as a partial in a new module so I inherited from Orchard.Users AdminController in my CustomModule and called base Index Action and added a custom route with higher priority:

```
//AdminController
public ActionResult IndexWithJS(UserIndexOptions options, PagerParameters pagerParameters)
{
    base.Index(options,pagerParameters);
    return View("Index");
}

//Route
[OrchardFeature("MyModule.Users")]
public class Routes : IRouteProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        yield return new RouteDescriptor()
        {
            Priority = 100,
            Route = new Route("Admin/Users/",
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"area", "MyModule.Users"},
                    {"controller", "Admin"},
                    {"action", "IndexWithJS"},
                },
                new RouteValueDictionary(),
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "area", "MyModule.Users" } },
                new MvcRouteHandler())
        };
    }

    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes)
    {
        foreach (var route in this.GetRoutes())
        {
            routes.Add(route);
        }
    }
}

//new Index.cshtml
@model Orchard.Users.ViewModels.UsersIndexViewModel

@Html.Partial("~/Modules/Orchard.Users/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml", Model)
@Script.Include("additionalscript.js");
```

As a result i get the same View as before but with no Groups, etc tabs. I need those tabs back ;). Has anyone had the same issue before and knhow how to do it without modifying any of the Orchard base modules ?

EDIT:My `INaigationProvider`:

```
public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Add(this.T("Users"), "11", menu =>
        {
            menu.Add(T("Users"), "1", item => item.Action("IndexWithJS", "Admin", new { area = "MyModule.Users" }).LocalNav().Permission(StandardPermissions.SiteOwner));
        });
    }
```

Now I'm getting the tabs, but User tab is duplicated. If I dont include my own NavigationProvider no tabs show up.

Comment: About your edit, this could have to do with the `LinkToFirstChild()` option which you can set on every item.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs are controlled by implementing the `INavigationProvider` interface and using the `LocalNav()` method for 3rd level menu items.

```
public void GetNavigation(NavigationBuilder builder) {
    builder.AddImageSet("webshop")
        .Add(T("Customers"), "7", menu => menu.Action(...})
        .Add(T("Details"), "0", item => item.Action(...}).LocalNav())
        .Add(T("History"), "1", item => item.Action(...).LocalNav())
        .Add(T("Contact"), "2", item => item.Action(...).LocalNav()));
}
```

ref: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/adding-admin-menu-items